# React - How to reuse/share a list NOT globally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As a developer I'd like to be able to reuse the **data source** for a content, for example a todo-list, at several points in my application.

I'd also like to let my **components** decide which data source they'd like to use.

The components should **update** whenever the list has been modified.

It is possible to have **multiple components with different data sources** at the same time (so no global store like most examples)

---

> The example scenario of a todo list might not be the best one, but for
>   the purpose of simplifying the problem I decided to use this

**Data Sources** might be for example:

- `AjaxTodoProvider`, which loads the ToDos from an API somewhere
- `FooBarTodoProvider`, which uses some funny random algorithm to create some
- ...

**Components** could be for example:

- `TodoListComponent`, which simply displays all ToDos
- `CarouselComponent`, which displays only one ToDo at a time.
- ...

---

### My attempts so far: (simplyfied, not running :D)

(Not working examples, just wrote those free hand in here)

#### Using a vanilla class as data provider

```
class TodoProvider {
  // ...
  constructor() {
    this.list = ['Drink milk', 'Resolve this problem'];
  }
  getResults() {
    return list;
  }
}

class ToDoComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.todos.map((todo) => <p key={todo}>{todo}</p>)
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var todos = new ToDoComponent()
    this.setState({
      todos: todos.getResults()
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ToDoComponent todos={this.state.todos} />
    )
  }
}
```

Problems with this one:

- Does not update by itself whenever the ToDo List changes

---

#### Using a provider component (context)

```
class ToDoProvider extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.todos = ['Watch a great movie']
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return { todos: this.todos; }
  }

  render() { ... }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ToDoProvider>
        <ToDoComponent todos={this.context.todos} />
      </ToDoProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

Problems with this one:

- The *context* does not really seems to be the best way of sharing data as it is kind of globally to the whole sub tree?

---

#### Using a provider component (props)

```
class ToDoProvider extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      todos: ['Eat some sushi']
    }
  }

  render() {
    return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
      todos: this.state.todos
    })
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ToDoProvider>
        <ToDoComponent todos={this.props.todos} />
      </ToDoProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

Problems with this one:

- Also does not look very great?

---

So I wonder what is the most elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got close with your context example:

```js
class ToDoProvider extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      todos: ['Watch a great movie']
    };
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return { todos: this.state.todos };
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

class ToDoComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.context.todos.map((todo) => <p key={todo}>{todo}</p>);
  }
}
ToDoComponent.contextTypes = { todos: React.PropTypes.any };

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ToDoProvider>
        <ToDoComponent />
      </ToDoProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

If you're looking to provide application state at multiple levels and locations of your app, you should be looking into Redux ( or at least a Flux library ).  It helps you with connecting components to disparate state, with less manual coding.